# Getting error while inserting more then 30 records to fusion table

Tags: javascript, c#

Getting Error while inserting more than 30 records to fusion Table.

Below code is working fine, but record if exist more than 30 records

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Authorization Request</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function auth() {
            var config = {
                'client_id': '607567025394-rmte05500pvsoj12dsrie1cbei5te506.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables',
                'immediate': false
            };
            gapi.auth.authorize(config, function () {
                console.log('login complete');
                console.log(gapi.auth.getToken());
            });
        }
        function insert_row() {
            gapi.client.setApiKey('AIzaSyAnEhw4Y7n5V7bN226wWo0tHs0Bd7jAzxA');

            gapi.client.load('fusiontables', 'v1', function () {                
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
                    var query = "INSERT INTO 1v228snvOypXSvzbtgZP_nhe_GcmBROV5G7lA0T0P(col0,col1,col2) VALUES ('a','a', 'a')"; 
                    gapi.client.fusiontables.query.sql({ sql: query }).execute(function (response) { console.log(response); });
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<button onclick="auth();">Authorize</button>
<br />
<button onclick="insert_row();">Insert Data</button>
<br />
<button onclick="showMap();">Show Map</button>
<br />
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

> Error:
>   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
>   Working_Insert_FT_Sample1.htm:33 `Object {code: 403, data: Array[1], message: "Rate Limit Exceeded", error: Object}`

Answer (score 0):

Check the docs here: https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/sql-reference

The SQL INSERT command can group multiple rows, so you only need one call to the server. That should avoid rate limits. Just concatenate the INSERT statements with ';' separator.

See this note!

> Note: You can list up to 500 INSERT statements, separated by
>   semicolons, in one request as long as the total size of the data does
>   not exceed 1 MB and the total number of table cells being added does
>   not exceed 10,000 cells. If you are inserting a large number of rows,
>   use the import method instead, which will be faster and more reliable
>   than using many SQL INSERT statements.

Note that the UPDATE and DELETE statements don't allow this! If you need those, you'll have to do more plumbing to your code, e.g. implementing delays and retries and get the job done in the backend.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your information. I would like to use import statements. But i don't know the exact syntax. If is possible then can you please share any sample codes. (C#, Javascript, Html)

Comment: Hi, Please share along with any good sample codes for import excel data to fusion table using c# or javascript or jquery.